# Upon form submit and errors are found the page refresh remains at the top but my form is at the bottom

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm creating a simple one pager with the benefits at the top and middle and the sign up at the bottom.

I'm currently testing form validation. When I enter invalid information to test error handling the controller correctly returns the same page with the errors listed, however the page is returned back at the very top and the user will not see that there were any error messages. They may in fact think that everything went well.

I have the option of moving the form to a new page, but I wanted to first see if it's possible to focus back on the bottom of the page where the form currently is.

I don't want get into a major undertaking here with javascript and workarounds. If it's possible without too much effort than I will try it, but if it's just easier to move the sign up form to another page I'll go for that.

Code? I'm not sure what code would be relevant here. Does the controller control page scrolling?

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $signUp = new SignUp();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SignUpType(), $signUp);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($signUp);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('japps_lfm_default_thanks'));
    }

    return $this->render('JAppsLFMBundle:AB:a.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *simple* solution would be to use anchors.

Example:

Your form could use an id attribute and your form action could use this id in the url:

```
<form id="my-form" action="{{ path('my_route') }}#my-form" ...>
...
</form>
```

Now if you submit the form and you have an error, the browser should jump to the form.

Side note: Scrolling is a client side thing, so PHP cannot help you with that. Only JavaScript or this simple hash based solution.

Comment: I've decided to go with a second page, thanks for your answer though.